# Unity - obstacle pass detection in endless runner game

Tags: unity-game-engine

What is the best way to detect if I passed obstacles (succeed to not collide with them) in an endless runner game?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please include a clear problem description and if possible some minimal code. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And take the tour!

Comment: I gave you an answer, but as 5th said, you should give more details in your question. Even if it is not exactly a piece of code what you are looking for, at least add an image or similar so other users can have a better understanding of what you are looking for. Otherwise you question will be or ignored or closed.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to place an empty GameObject (no 3d/3d model attached to them) in the parts of the path which are clear (no obstacles). And to those empty GameObjects I would add a collider which is triggered.

Then I will add a script to those empty GameObjects which will have this piece of code:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        //Do something, like for example increase a counter of points
        // or show a success message...
    }
```

So when the player goes through these empty GameObjects, it will trigger some actions that represents success.